# Jquery change function is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Initially I have disabled `To date` field,After selecting `From date` only I want to allow it to choose.I wrote code for that,But its not working.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#levTo').attr('disabled', 'true');
  $('#levFrom').change(function() {
    $('#levTo').attr('disabled', 'false');
  })
  pastDaysdisable()
});

function pastDaysdisable() {
  var dtToday = new Date();
  var month = dtToday.getMonth() + 1;
  var day = dtToday.getDate();
  var year = dtToday.getFullYear();
  if (month < 10)
    month = '0' + month.toString();
  if (day < 10)
    day = '0' + day.toString();

  var maxDate = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;
  $('#levFrom,#levTo').attr('min', maxDate);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
  <label class="col-xs-12">Date From</label>
  <input type="date" id="levFrom" class="col-xs-12 form-control levFrom required">
</div>

<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
  <label class="col-xs-12">Date To</label>
  <input type="date" id="levTo" class="col-xs-12 form-control levTo required">
</div>
```

Also,I am trying to restrict `To date` based on `From date`
`To date` should not allow to select the date before `from date` which I have choosed.How to do it?
I know its possible in date picker.But,I want to achieve it in `input type=date.`

Comment: why you removed `from date` format? I want to display it form current date only

Answer (score 2):

Use `$('#levTo').prop('disabled', false);`

> Use the prop() method to enable or disable elements when using jQuery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#levTo').attr('disabled', 'true');
  $('#levFrom').change(function() {
    $('#levTo').prop('disabled', false);
    pastDaysdisable($('#levFrom').val())
  })
});

function pastDaysdisable(date) {


  $('#levFrom,#levTo').attr('min', date);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
  <label class="col-xs-12">Date From</label>
  <input type="date" id="levFrom" class="col-xs-12 form-control levFrom required">
</div>

<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
  <label class="col-xs-12">Date To</label>
  <input type="date" id="levTo" class="col-xs-12 form-control levTo required">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks.can you give me any suggestion for my second question?

Comment: @user7397787 Try take a look now

Comment: it should display from current date only

Comment: @user7397787 you say "To date should not allow to select the date before from date" thats why i changed it.

Comment: yes.But `from date` should allow to select from current date only.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
$('#levFrom').on('change keyup paste',function (){
            $('#levTo').removeAttr('disabled');
        })
```

instead of:

```
$('#levFrom').change(function() {
$('#levTo').attr('disabled', 'false');
```

})